# F#: How to navigate between pages in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#

I I have created a main page like this:

```
namespace Foo

open System
open Xamarin.Forms
open Xamarin.Forms.Xaml

type MainPage() =
    inherit ContentPage()
    let _ = base.LoadFromXaml(typeof<MainPage>)
    let baseLayout = base.Content :?> AbsoluteLayout
    let backgroundImage = baseLayout.Children.[0] :?> Image
    let navigatonGrid = baseLayout.Children.[1] :?> Grid
    let navigatonImage = navigatonGrid.Children.[0] :?> Image
    let navigatonButton = navigatonGrid.Children.[1] :?> Button

    let onButtonClicked sender args =
        let loginPage = new NavigationPage(FacebookLoginPage())
        Navigation.PushAsync(loginPage) |> ignore


    let populateImages =
        backgroundImage.Source <- ImageSource.FromResource("foo.jpg")
        navigatonImage.Source <- ImageSource.FromResource("bar.jpg")

    do
        populateImages
        navigatonButton.Clicked.AddHandler(new EventHandler(onButtonClicked))
```

And I wrap the Content page in the App.xaml.fs like this:

```
namespace foo

open Xamarin.Forms

type App() =
    inherit Application(MainPage = NavigationPage(MainPage()))
```

However, it does not compile.  I get this:

> /Users/jamesdixon/Projects/foo/foo/MainPage.xaml.fs(9,9):
>   Error FS0039: The value, namespace, type or module 'Navigation' is not
>   defined. Maybe you want one of the following:   NavigationPage
>   navigatonGrid   navigatonButton   navigatonImage
>   NavigationEventArgs (FS0039) (foo.Mobile.iOS)

However, I can't add the "this" keyword because I get this error:

> /Users/jamesdixon/Projects/foo/foo.Mobile/MainPage.xaml.fs(9,9):
>   Error FS0039: The value, namespace, type or module 'this' is not
>   defined. Maybe you want one of the following:   ThisAssembly (FS0039)
>   (SameRoom.foo.iOS)

Is the problem that the button click cannot be static?  If so, what is the correct syntax for the event handler?

Update:  Based on the comments below, I tried this:

```
open System
open Xamarin.Forms
open Xamarin.Forms.Xaml

type MainPage(x) as self =
    inherit ContentPage()
    let _ = base.LoadFromXaml(typeof<MainPage>)
```

But now I get

> The type 'ContentPage' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a self-identifier:

```
type MainPage() as this =
```

Comment: Also - If you use `this` for member declarations, you might want to consider a different self identifier name, such as `self`, to make it clear what you're doing.

Comment: Upped. Thank you for taking the time to straighten this one out.

Comment: that does not work - see my update in the original question

Comment: You can now access self.Navigation (as you implicitly tried to do in your question, and as Tyler's answer clarified).

I don't get your question as your sample code makes no use of the identifier `self`. Are you really saying that the mere addition of `as self` to your three lines of code leads to an error? That doesn't sound possible.

Comment: That is exactly it Charles.  Adding the "self" makes the red squiggly under ContentPage and that error appears.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Does the error depend on the name "MainPage" or the presence of LoadFromXaml?

Comment: so the problem with the red squiggly seems to be a VS for Mac issue, not a F# one.  This is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this is due to F# methods being translated to static methods (at least that's my understanding). The static method doesn't have access to the base type's method.

If you define `onButtonClicked` as follows, it should work for you

```
member this.onButtonClicked sender args =
    let loginPage = new NavigationPage(FacebookLoginPage())
    this.Navigation.PushAsync(loginPage) |> ignore
```

Using the `member this.onButtonClicked` syntax creates a class method, rather than a static method on the class. This then lets you access `this.Navigation` on the class as you expect.

As for your problem with the constructor ordering, there are two solutions:

This link should explain how to do it in the constructor: 
https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/classes/#accessing-the-instance-via-this-in-a-do-block

However, according to that article, this is bad practice, an alternative would be to assign the handler in the `OnStart` or `PageAppearing` Lifecycle methods of the page.

Comment: If I make the event handler a class method, I have to put it below the do command., which means the addHandler function can't find it.  So where do I put that?  Make that a member and call it from the .ctor ?